# Update MySQL Date field with single INT from another field?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

For simplicity sake, I have two fields within a table:

- Date 1 (YYYY-MM-DD format)
- Day (single or two digit day format, 1-31)

I want to be able to update Date 1 using the value within Day but I DO NOT want to make multiple calls to do so (first a select, fetch results, then update with the result from the same table).

ultimately, the 'design' of my call (which does not work) would be:

> UPDATE table SET Date 1 =
>   DATE(Y-(M+1)-(value of Day));

or in php:

```
date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+1, VALUE(Day), date('Y')));
```

is this possible?

UPDATE

==

While I have been able to utilize some of the code below, I am not sure MYSQL is 'smart' enough to run the calculation as I have it. My new code is:

> UPDATE    table SET   Date 1=
>   CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),
>   INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'-',Day1)

While this returns the correct 'new month' and 'new day', the year will be wrong WHEN the current month is December.

For example: If the current date is 2010-12-02. The preferred data in the Day field is 12. Once our script has processed, the Date 1 field should be updated to 2011-01-12 but in the code above it will only output to 2010-01-12.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Does "Day" store an actual date day number or are you incrementing it? I think getting rid of your Day field and using date manipulation functions would make it far easier for you. You run a big risk by using two columns to store the same data you could get from one.

Comment: @Cfreak - it is not the same data. Date 1 field can be updated at any time but when certain actions occur, the  DAY portion of that field is updated to the value stored in Day field. To your last point, having two fields with 'similar' data, one being a tinyint is hardly "a big risk"

Answer (score 1):

not tested, but i think what you're missing is [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE table SET datefield = CONCAT(YEAR(datefield),'-',MONTH(datefield),'-',dayfield);
```

after rereading you questioon, it sounds like you want to add the days, that would be like this (not tested, too - take a look at [DATE_ADD and INTERVAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)):

```
UPDATE table SET datefield = DAT_ADD(datefield, INTERVAL dayfield DAYS);
```

Comment: you have the first part of the question exactly right, now the only 'additional' thing is to increase the MONTH value by one (so when the record is updated, the month is increased by one, the day value is changed (as your code does) and the year corresponds accordingly (i.e. if the update is occurring Dec 2, 2010; Day field is 12; after process is run, Date 1 is now Jan 12, 2011

Comment: I am not looking to 'add' days, only change the day itself to the following month.